# Can Terraform watch a directory for changes?

Tags: terraform

I want to monitor a directory of files, and if one of them changes, to re-upload and run some other tasks. My previous solution involved monitoring the individual files, but this is error-prone as some files may be forgotten:

```
resource "null_resource" "deploy_files" {    
  triggers = {
    file1 = "${sha1(file("my-dir/file1"))}"
    file2 = "${sha1(file("my-dir/file2"))}"
    file3 = "${sha1(file("my-dir/file3"))}"
    # have I forgotten one?
  }

  # Copy files then run a remote script.
  provisioner "file" { ... }
  provisioner "remote-exec: { ... }
}
```

My next solution is to take a hash of the directory structure in one resource, and use this hash as a trigger in the second:

```
resource "null_resource" "watch_dir" {
  triggers = {
    always = "${uuid()}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "find my-dir  -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sha1sum | sha1sum > mydir-checksum"
  }
}


resource "null_resource" "deploy_files" {    
  triggers = {
    file1 = "${sha1(file("mydir-checksum"))}"
  }

  # Copy files then run a remote script.
  provisioner "file" { ... }
  provisioner "remote-exec: { ... }
}
```

This works okay, except changes to `mydir-checksum` are only picked up after the first `apply`. So I need to `apply` twice, which isn't great. It's a bit of a kludge.

I can't see a more obvious way to monitor an entire directory for changes in content. Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: Use `make` to generate the hash and then use this as trigger? Because I am not aware of any other solution. Also `find my-dir -type f -exec sha1sum +` should be faster.

Comment: You mean `make` as an external script that to run before terraform?

Comment: This is an interesting question, and I’ve never used Terraform in this way. But I wonder if this is just something Terraform wasn’t made to do - it manages infrastructure; file system handling seems like a second-class citizen. I would probably suggest this is where you want a wrapper script around Terraform to shape it to your needs.

Comment: @Joe yes. You could have `make` task the would check and generate sum file for your directory and then use that file content as a trigger.

Comment: Thanks both. Agreed, the fact that this isn't directly supported might be a hint. But there are lots of examples that involve watching files and watching a dir of files isn't so different. The files in question are Docker Stack deployment files plus supporting config, which I think are in Terraform territory.

Answer (score 44):

In Terraform 0.12 and later, one can use a [for expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html) combined with a [fileset function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/fileset.html) and one of the hashing functions to calculate a combined checksum for files in a directory:

```
> sha1(join("", [for f in fileset(path.cwd, "*"): filesha1("${path.cwd}/${f}")]))
"77e0b2785eb7405ea5b3b610c33c3aa2dccb90ea"
```

The code above will calculate a `sha1` checksum for each file in the current directory that matches the name pattern, join the checksums in a string and, finally, calculate a checksum for the resulting string. So the `null_resource` example would look like this with the expression above as a trigger:

```
resource "null_resource" "deploy_files" {    
  triggers = {
    dir_sha1 = sha1(join("", [for f in fileset("my-dir", "*"): filesha1("my-dir/${f}")]))
  }

  provisioner "file" { ... }
  provisioner "remote-exec: { ... }
}
```

Note that `fileset("my-dir", "*")` does not take into account files in sub-directories of `my-dir`. If you want to include checksums of those use the name pattern `**` instead of `*`.

Comment: And in case you are accessing the files in an upper directory you need to pass it to the filesha1 function as well. You can use a local to avoid duplication.

E.g.: [for f in fileset("${path.module}/../website", "*"): filesha1("${path.module}/../website/${f}")]

Comment: if you are doing this on the contents of a tf module, how would you exclude hidden files / the state file from this operation?

Comment: This doesn't work since "The path is automatically removed from the resulting set of file names": https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/fileset

Comment: I got it to work like this:  sha1(join("", [for f in fileset(".", "./path/to/files/*") : filesha1(f)]))

Answer (score 32):

You can use the [`"archive_file"` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/archive/d/archive_file.html):

```
data "archive_file" "init" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir = "data/"
  output_path = "data.zip"
}

resource "null_resource" "provision-builder" {
  triggers = {
    src_hash = "${data.archive_file.init.output_sha}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo Touché"
  }
}
```

The null resource will be reprovisioned if and only if the hash of the archive has changed. The archive will be rebuilt during refresh whenever the contents of `source_dir` (in this example `data/`) change.

Comment: That's really interesting! I think this depends on the determinism / repeatbility of the output zipped bytes with regard to the input. Is this something that works by accident or is the stability of the zip defined?

Comment: Agreed, I haven't thought about that. Luckily, my implementation doesn't add timestamps or anything to the zip file itself, but even such things as updated timestamps of the *zipped files* will invalidate the data, change the hash and invalidate the resource.

Answer (score 7):

I also had the same requirement, I implemented it in below fashion using [`data.external`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html) resource:

- Written a script which will give me the checksum of the directory using `md5sum`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  #
  # This script calculates the MD5 checksum on a directory
  #

  # Exit if any of the intermediate steps fail
  set -e

  # Extract "DIRECTORY" argument from the input into
  # DIRECTORY shell variables.
  # jq will ensure that the values are properly quoted
  # and escaped for consumption by the shell.
  eval "$(jq -r '@sh "DIRECTORY=\(.directory)"')"

  # Placeholder for whatever data-fetching logic your script implements
  CHECKSUM=`find ${DIRECTORY} -type f | LC_ALL=C sort | xargs shasum -a 256 | awk '{ n=split ($2, tokens, /\//); print $1 " " tokens[n]} ' |  shasum -a 256 | awk '{ print $1 }'`

  # Safely produce a JSON object containing the result value.
  # jq will ensure that the value is properly quoted
  # and escaped to produce a valid JSON string.
  jq -n --arg checksum "$CHECKSUM" '{"checksum":$checksum}'
  ```
- Created the `data.external` as below

  ```
  data "external" "trigger" {
    program = ["${path.module}/dirhash.sh"]

    query {
      directory = "${path.module}/<YOUR_DIR_PATH_TO_WATCH>"
    }
  }
  ```
- Use above resource `results` output as a trigger to `null_resource`

  ```
  resource "null_resource" "deploy_files" {
    # Changes to any configuration file, requires the re-provisioning
    triggers {
      md5 = "${data.external.trigger.result["checksum"]}"
    }
    ...
  }
  ```

PS: script has dependency on `jq`

Update:
Updated the checksum calculation logic to neutralise the effect of find on different platforms.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much. I saw the external resource thing, then I saw the JSON requirement and dismissed it. I'll give this approach a go.

Comment: @Joe, I have updated the checksum logic to neutralise the `find` effect across the platform. Please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: I have been using this for a while. It works extremely well. Well done.

Answer (score 3):

A variation of gn00m's answer worked for me

```
triggers = {
dir_sha1    = sha1(join("", [for f in fileset(path.root, "src/**") : filesha1(f)]))
}
```

where src is the folder I want to track

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the solution by @gn00m didn't work because the folder to check is an input argument, and it failed with `Call to function "filesha1" failed: open -my-file-: no such file or directory`

Adding the folder in the last part of the code fixes the issue.

```
sha1(join("", [for f in fileset(var.folder, "*"): filesha1("${var.folder}/${f}")]))
```

Comment: While this input is valuable, it should be an edit @gn00m's answer, not a separate one. Btw: I have just edited it.

Answer (score 2):

I use this for Cloud Functions in GCP where the Cloud Function only depends on the file name, so I need to force a change to the filename when any file changes or else taint the Cloud Function for every deploy. I solved it using locals so there's no extra file being created like the `archive_file` solution. The cavaet is you need to hardcode the filenames, which may be acceptable in certain use cases.

```
locals {
  # Hard code a list of files in the dir
  cfn_files = [
    "cfn/requirements.txt",
    "cfn/main.py",
  ]

  # Get the MD5 of each file in the directory
  cfn_md5sums = [for f in local.cfn_files : filemd5(f)]

  # Join the MD5 sums together and take the MD5 of all of them
  # Effectively checksumming the pieces of the dir you care about
  cfn_dirchecksum = md5(join("-", local.cfn_md5sums))
}
...

data "archive_file" "cfn" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir = "cfn"
  output_path = "cfn/build/${local.cfn_dirchecksum}.zip"
}
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "archive" {
  name   = data.archive_file.cfn.output_path
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.cfn_bucket.name
  source = data.archive_file.cfn.output_path
}
...
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "function" {
  project     = var.project_id
  region      = var.region
  runtime     = "python37"

  source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.cfn_bucket.name
  source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.archive.name
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that Terraform provide any directory tree traversal function, so the only solution that I can think of is to use some kind of external tooling to do so, like Make:

```
all: tf.plan

tf.plan: hash *.tf
        terraform plan -o $@

hash: some/dir
        find $^ -type f -exec sha1sum {} + > $@

.PHONY: all hash
```

and then in your Terraform file:

```
resource "null_resource" "deploy_files" {    
  triggers = {
    file1 = "${file("hash")}"
  }

  # Copy files then run a remote script.
  provisioner "file" { ... }
  provisioner "remote-exec: { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll think about it.