# Remote Build in Terraform for Python Azure Functions App Doesn't Update Function Code

Tags: python, azure, terraform, azure-functions, github-actions

I'm deploying an Azure Functions App via Terraform with a Python runtime. Everything seems to be running okay on the Azure side, but the Python code is failing in the function itself. So naturally, I've updated the python code within the function and pushing the changes but the function itself is not updating on Azure. I've found that you can force update the .zip with `filemd5` if you're using a Blob storage to host the file, but I'm using a remote build to ensure the Python packages are installed/accessible.

Can I do a force update of the `zip_deploy_file` in the functions app definition somehow? Or do I have to do a `terraform destory` and rebuild the whole thing from scratch?

```
resource "null_resource" "pip" {
  triggers = {
    requirements_md5 = "${filemd5("../src/requirements.txt")}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {    
    command = "pip install --target='.python_packages/lib/site-packages' -r requirements.txt"
    working_dir = "../src"
  }
}

data "archive_file" "functions" {
  type = "zip"
  source_dir = "../src"
  output_path = "../src/functions.zip"
  depends_on = [null_resource.pip]
} 

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "function_app" {
  name                = "func-${var.application_name}-${var.environment_name}-fnapp"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location

  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.functions.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.functions.primary_access_key
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.main.id

  site_config {
    application_insights_key               = azurerm_application_insights.main.instrumentation_key
    application_insights_connection_string = azurerm_application_insights.main.connection_string

    application_stack {
      python_version = "3.11"
    }
    cors {
      allowed_origins     = ["https://portal.azure.com"]
      support_credentials = true
    }
  }

  app_settings = {
    "ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD" = true
    "BLOBSTORAGE_CXNSTR" = "${var.blobstorage_cxnstr}"
    "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT" = true
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" = "python"
  }

  zip_deploy_file = data.archive_file.functions.output_path
  depends_on = [data.archive_file.functions]

  identity {
    type         = "SystemAssigned, UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.functions.id]
  }
}
```

[image: App Settings in the functions app configuration tab]

Note: I'm also not entirely sure if the `null_resource` is superfluous now that I've changed it from `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` to remote build now (first foray into terraform as well as azure functions).

Comment: Can you show the output of a `terraform plan` when you change the code in your python function?

Comment: One think that is kind of suspicious is that null_resource with the triggers, if that runs a pipeline where you get a new container on every run that step might not run

Comment: I solved this by renaming the .zip every time it deploys. I added a `random_string` resource and forces replacement of the deployment package every time.

Comment: Nice workaround ... but that will force deployment even if nothing has changed, if all you have is the one function it might not be a big deal, but with a lot of functions that will slow down deployments significantly

Comment: Yeah, fortunately for my use case, I currently only have one function and will have max 4 or 5 in the end. May not be the right move if running larger function apps. Will post again if I find a better solution, but for now moving onto the next error, haha!

Comment: I was just thinking that instead of something random in the name you can use something like the md5 you used on the trigger, maybe something like this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66501021/7599833 ... that way you could calculate a combined checksum for files in the function directory and use that as the zip name

Comment: ah, that is a good idea! Thanks!